# What is the blank part in process sections. [Operating System]

Tags: operating-system

[image: Process sections]

[When a program is loaded into the memory and it becomes a process, it can be divided into four sections ─ stack, heap, text and data. The following image shows a simplified layout of a process inside main memory.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_processes.htm)

I was wondering what does the blank part means, and what does the arrow means. if anyone can help with this. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That area is usually used by the `stack` section, because the `stack` can grow/shrink based on the depth of current `call stack`. as your link states that

> The process Stack contains the temporary data such as method/function
>   parameters, return address and local variables.

### ***How the depth of call stack grows?***

To really understand this you would have to know how `assembler` deals with function calls. but I will try to provide a simple explanation. So when your code calls a `function`, its associated data is pushed to `stack` and the `stack` grows downward and ***when the `execution` of `function` completes, its local data is no longer needed so the `stack` shrinks back.***

But when your code contains nested `function` calls, that is `function A` calls `function B` and `function B` calls `function C`. in this case stack keeps growing.

***And if your code contains too many nested `function` `calls`, stack of your process may expand such that there is no more empty area.*** when that happens (probably when you implement a `recursive` `function` without correct base case), we get our beloved [stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror).

***Following section provides a visual explanation of this process***

let's say you are running a program and in pseudo code it looks something as following

```
fun first(arguments){
   second();
}

fun second(arguments){
   third();
}

fun third(arguments){
   print("hello");
}

fun main(){
   first(arguments);  // line 1
   third(arguments);  // line 2
}
```

When your program starts, its `memory` block would look something as following.

[image]

Because as your program starts it calls the `main method`, the `stack` will hold all the local `variable` associated with the main function.

When main function calls the `first function`, `stack` will grow downward as local `variable` and other stuff related to `first function` would be pushed to `stack`. so it look as following.

[image]

because `first function` internally calls `second` and `second function` internally calls `third` the stack will expand to accommodate all the data associated with `second` and `third` `functions`.

***Please note that stack would only grow for nested `function` calls.*** for example when first line in `main function` has executed and the `execution` moves to line 2, `stack` will decrease in size.